# Optimise query with 2x LEFT JOIN from same table

Tags: mysql, left-join, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    match_main.checked,
    match_main.match_main_id,
    match_main.updated,
    match_main.created
FROM
    match_main
        LEFT JOIN
    match_team AS mt1 ON mt1.match_main_id = match_main.match_main_id
        AND mt1.team_number = 1
        AND mt1.version_number = 0
        LEFT JOIN
    match_team AS mt2 ON mt2.match_main_id = match_main.match_main_id
        AND mt2.team_number = 2
        AND mt2.version_number = 0
WHERE
    mt1.team_id = 557949
        OR mt2.team_id = 557949
```

Where `match_main` is a table of sports matches and `match_team` is a table of the teams that played in a given sports match.

`match_main` contains around 5m records and `match_team` contains around 10m records.

The query above takes over 5 mins to return about 1700 records and I can't figure out how to optimise it further.

This is the `EXPLAIN` query output:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type |   table    | partitions |  type  |                                                    possible_keys                                                    |                   key                    | key_len |                   ref                    |  rows   | filtered |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | match_main | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                | NULL                                     | NULL    | NULL                                     | 4756279 |      100 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mt1        | NULL       | eq_ref | uq__match_team__match__team_id__version,uq__match_team__match__team_num__version,ix__match_team__match_main_id,comp | uq__match_team__match__team_num__version | 6       | itf.match_main.match_main_id,const,const |       1 |      100 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mt2        | NULL       | eq_ref | uq__match_team__match__team_id__version,uq__match_team__match__team_num__version,ix__match_team__match_main_id,comp | uq__match_team__match__team_num__version | 6       | itf.match_main.match_main_id,const,const |       1 |      100 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

Here are the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` outputs:

```
CREATE TABLE `match_main` (
  `match_main_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `checked` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_main_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2121471809 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `match_team` (
  `match_team_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `match_main_id` int NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int NOT NULL,
  `team_number` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `version_number` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_team_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uq__match_team__match__team_id__version` (`match_main_id`,`team_id`,`version_number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uq__match_team__match__team_num__version` (`match_main_id`,`team_number`,`version_number`),
  KEY `ix__match_team__team_id` (`team_id`),
  KEY `ix__match_team__match_main_id` (`match_main_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__match_team__match_main_id` FOREIGN KEY (`match_main_id`) REFERENCES `match_main` (`match_main_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__match_team__team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES `team` (`team_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9297542 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I need to retain the two aliased `match_team` tables as when I expand this query I'll need to link these tables to the `team` tables. This is so I can return an output of a match on a single row with columns for details on all the individual teams that played in a match. I've excluded this to keep the MRE simple.

Comment: MySQL isn't able to use indexes to optimize `OR` conditions, so it has to do a full scan. Instead of using `OR`, write two queries and combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 2):

Redefine the column order in one of the unique keys:

```
ALTER TABLE match_team
  DROP KEY `uq__match_team__match__team_num__version`,
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `uq__match_team__team_num__version__match` (`team_number`,`version_number`,`match_main_id`);
```

Then try this query:

```
SELECT m.checked, m.match_main_id, m.updated, m.created
FROM match_team AS mt1
INNER JOIN match_team AS mt2
  ON mt1.match_main_id = mt2.match_main_id
INNER JOIN match_main AS m
  ON m.match_main_id = mt1.match_main_id
WHERE 557949 IN (mt1.team_id, mt2.team_id)
  AND mt1.team_number = 1
  AND mt1.version_number = 0
  AND mt2.team_number = 2
  AND mt2.version_number = 0;
```

It should use the new `uq__match_team__team_num__version__match` index for both `mt1` and `mt2`, then join to `match_main` by its primary key. This eliminates the table-scan of 4 million rows on `match_main`.

Here's the EXPLAIN report I got when I tested:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: mt1
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: uq__match_team__match__team_id__version,uq__match_team__team_num__version__match,ix__match_team__match_main_id
          key: uq__match_team__team_num__version__match
      key_len: 2
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: mt2
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: uq__match_team__match__team_id__version,uq__match_team__team_num__version__match,ix__match_team__match_main_id
          key: uq__match_team__team_num__version__match
      key_len: 6
          ref: const,const,test.mt1.match_main_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: m
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: test.mt1.match_main_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this - a neat solution and something that's definitely given me food for thought on how to index situations like this. However, I'm not sure it will work for this specific example as there are edge cases where there isn't always a `match_team` with a `team_number` of 1 (or 2 for that matter). That's why I have to use `LEFT JOIN` above - I still want to return the `match_main` record :(

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the second JOIN? You could try with just one:

```
SELECT 
    mm.checked,
    mm.match_main_id,
    mm.updated,
    mm.created
FROM match_team AS mt 
   JOIN match_main AS mm ON mm.match_main_id = mt.match_main_id 
WHERE mt.team_id = 557949 AND mt.version_number = 0 
  AND mt.team_number in (1,2);
```

Also, the `LEFT JOIN` becomes a normal `JOIN` when you move the condition to the `WHERE`-clause.

See a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jfffhQWS)

Comment: Hi - see the final paragraph in my question as to why I need the two `match_team` joins

Comment: OK, since you limited the query to a single team (557949), the other JOIN didn't seem relevant.

Comment: A team can play in a match as either the first or the second team :)

Comment: And still it would be the same team. The `team_number` would tell you if it was the first or the second.